# Dbeaver with SDKMAN JRE JDK location

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I'm trying to configure Dbeaver with a custom location of my Java installation as I have it installed via SDKMAN.

To do that, I have added the `vm` parameter to the `dbearver.ini` file, so now when Dbeaver launchs, it searchs for my Java installation in that folder. The contents of my `dbearver.ini` are:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-showsplash
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-vm 
~/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u161-oracle/jre/bin 
-vmargs
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
```

I tried with many paths as the `vm` argument but didn't get it working with anyone. I always get the following error:

[image]

As the error asks for JRE or JDK, I don't know to which executable file should I point.

I have the following installations of Java 8 at the standard location SDKMAN places them (`~/.sdkman/candidates/java`)

- 8u161-oracle
- 8u152-zulu

Could you please help me to get Dbeaver working? I don't want to have duplicated installations of Java in my machine.

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify the full path (`/home/username/.sdkman/`) instead of the relative path (`~/`)?

Comment: @Jos BINGO! Place it as answer and I will select it as the correct one. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, DBeaver does not use path substitution, i.e. it does not replace `~` by the user's home folder.

Instead, use the full path:

`/home/[username]/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u161-oracle/jre/bin`